# Como dejar habilitado solamente el checkbox seleccionado en angular 9?

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, mat-table

Hay alguna forma de desactivar (con disabled) los demás checkbox que no están seleccionados excepto el que seleccione ? Tengo este código.

HTML:

```
       <table mat-table [dataSource]="data">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                        Nombre
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
                           {{ element.nombre}} 
                    </td>
             </ng-container>

             <ng-container matColumnDef="products">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > productos </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i = index">

                        <mat-checkbox   
                        [(ngModel)]="element.producto"
                        [checked]="select === i"
                        (change)="select = i;">
                        </mat-checkbox>

           </td>
           </ng-container>

           <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="listcolumns"></tr>
           <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: listcolumns"></tr>
      </table>
```

TYPESCRIPT:

```
selected = -1;
listcolumns: string[] = ['name','products'];
public data: MatTableDataSource<any>;
```

Este fragmento de código , proviene de un mat-table , donde select = -1 , lo que hace es que cada ves que pique a un check se desactive el otro check anterior, pero me gustaría que si pico a un check , los demás checkbock se desabilitaran con disabled excepto el que esta seleccionado, hay alguna forma de hacer eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrías añadir otra propiedad donde indique que el producto ya esta marcado, y lo validas internamente con eso, para deshabilitar los productos que no estén como marcados

```
elemento.selected
```

así

```
  [checked]="select === i && elemento.selected == true"
```

Comment: gracias , claro si es posible tambien hacerlo internamente., pero bueno me resulto muy bien